# Why am I receiving a message Could not find configuration node: databases/database @id=master?

Tags: configuration

Here is what I am hoping to do: 
I would like to upload a media item to the Media Library.

Here is my Code:

[image]

Here is my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>

    </configSections>

    <startup>

        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />

    </startup>
  <connectionStrings configSource="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />

</configuration>
```

and ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- 
    Sitecore connection strings.
    All database connections for Sitecore are configured here.
  -->
  <add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=Bushcmsdb01dev;Initial Catalog=intranet.dev_core;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ssa-ap-sitecoredev;Password=$eioMaSXln" />
  <add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=Bushcmsdb01dev;Initial Catalog=intranet.dev_master;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ssa-ap-sitecoredev;Password=$eioMaSXln" />
  <add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=Bushcmsdb01dev;Initial Catalog=intranet.dev_web;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ssa-ap-sitecoredev;Password=$eioMaSXln" />
  <add name="reporting" connectionString="Data Source=Bushcmsdb01dev;Initial Catalog=intranet.dev_reporting;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ssa-ap-sitecoredev;Password=$eioMaSXln" />
  <add name="wffm" connectionString="Data Source=Bushcmsdb01dev;Initial Catalog=Sitecore_Wffm;User ID=ssa-ap-sitecoredev;Password=$eioMaSXln"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Note: I am using Sitecore 8.2, and I attempting to do this in a console app outside of our Sitecore solution. If this cannot be done, then I will explore using the .web api

Comment: This cannot be done

Comment: Thank you for your comment, is the right direction using the Web api?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. I believe this might be longer discussion so I suggest to move it to https://sitecore.chat

Comment: I joined Sitecore chat ... but in a nutshell, I just want to be able to update the Sitecore Media Library outside of our Sitecore environment. We are on Sitecore 8.2, but not using Sitecore MVC currently.

Comment: Could you please explain the use case here? it will give a good idea about the solution to your problem. I guess you want to upload the media programmatically from public site if so see this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-to-upload-an-image-programmatically-from-url

Comment: Please check <database> node exists in sitecore.config file?  <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or Processing or ContentManagement">

Comment: Just for the record; it absolutely IS possible to make Sitecore Api calls from a console application. But it's a very complicated setup and I would not recommend it. ItemApi is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but a bit of a rabbit hole.  Copy the entire <sitecore> config node into your app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigReader, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    </configSections>
    <sitecore database="SqlServer">
        //
    </sitecore>      
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings configSource="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
</configuration>
```

Comment out any <sc.include/> nodes, in <configStores> update arg0 to remove the leading slash (copy those files from your Sitecore solution into the appropriate place, or add them to the project and select to copy on build)

```
<configStores>
  <add name="domains" type="Sitecore.Configuration.XmlConfigStore, Sitecore.Kernel" factoryMethod="LoadFromFile" arg0="App_Config/Security/Domains.config" />
  <add name="globalRoles" type="Sitecore.Configuration.XmlConfigStore, Sitecore.Kernel" factoryMethod="LoadFromFile" arg0="App_Config/Security/GlobalRoles.config" />
</configStores>
```

Now wrap your code in a security disabler and an event disabler

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
using (new EventDisabler())
{
    MediaCreatorOptions options = new MediaCreatorOptions();
    options.FileBased = false;
    options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
    options.KeepExisting = false;
    options.Versioned = false;
    options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library/...";
    options.Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

    MediaCreator creator = new MediaCreator();
    var mediaItem = creator.CreateFromFile("...", options);
}
```

Run the code and add references to any assemblies it complains are missing.  Once you have this working you can experiment on cutting out any config sections you don't need.  If I was you though, I'd go the API route.

Edit: if you have a running instance of Sitecore you might not see the new items as they are not in the Sitecore cache and Sitecore doesn't know you've created them.  Stop and start IIS to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo-quality code I once wrote which uses REST. It's very hard-coded and opinionated, but enough to steer you in the right direction. Let me know if you have any questions. You'll need to be familiar with setting up WebAPI controllers and securing them.

```
[Route("UploadMedia")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadMedia()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    var creator = new MediaCreator();
    var masterDb = DatabaseHelper.MasterDatabase;

    try
    {
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        var languageCode = provider.FormData["language"];

        var versioned = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageCode))
        {
            languageCode = "en";
            versioned = false;
        }

        var language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(languageCode);

        var ids = new List<Guid>();

        foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
        {
            var fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');

            var fileKey = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
            var index = fileKey.Substring(4);

            var pathKey = $"path{index}";
            var path = provider.FormData[pathKey];

            var nameKey = $"name{index}";
            var name = provider.FormData[nameKey];

            if (path == null || name == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var pathItem = masterDb.GetItem(path);
            if (pathItem == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            var localFileName = file.LocalFileName + extension;
            File.Copy(file.LocalFileName, localFileName, true);

            name = MakeSeoFriendly(name);
            var destinationPath = $"{path}/{name}";

            using (new LanguageSwitcher(language))
            {
                var destinationItem = (MediaItem)masterDb.GetItem(destinationPath);
                if (destinationItem == null)
                {
                    var options = new MediaCreatorOptions
                    {
                        FileBased = false,
                        IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
                        OverwriteExisting = false,
                        Versioned = versioned,
                        Destination = destinationPath,
                        Database = masterDb,
                        Language = language
                    };

                    var mediaItem = creator.CreateFromFile(localFileName, options);
                    ids.Add(mediaItem.ID.Guid);
                }
                else
                {
                    var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(destinationItem);
                    using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(localFileName)))
                    {
                        media.SetStream(fileStream, extension);
                    }

                    ids.Add(destinationItem.ID.Guid);
                }
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ids);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}

private string MakeSeoFriendly(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    str = Regex.Replace(str, "[\\'\\`]", string.Empty).ToLower();
    str = Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z\\-0-9]", "-").ToLower();
    str = Regex.Replace(str, "[\\-]{2,}", "-");
    if (str.StartsWith("-"))
    {
        str = str.Substring(1);
    }

    if (str.EndsWith("-"))
    {
        str = str.TrimEnd('-');
    }

    return str;
}
```

You then consume it from your console app:

```
var f = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StringContent("file1"), "file1" },
    { new StringContent("/sitecore/media library/Images"), "path1" },
    { new StringContent("name of the image"), "name1" },
    { new StringContent("en"), "language" }
};

var fileContent = new StreamContent(fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
    Name = "file1",
    FileName = fuImage.PostedFile.FileName
};
f.Add(fileContent);

var r = await YourRestClient.PostAsync("yourapi/UploadMedia", f);
var sitecoreIds = await r.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Guid>>();
```