# How to replace image in sitecore media library programmatically

Tags: sitecore-api, media-library

```
Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var item = master.GetItem(new ID("{493E6479-D647-4120-A543-B20924F24978}"));

item.Editing.BeginEdit();

//I want to replace sitecore existing image from another source 

 item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: Clarify your exact requirement please

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField` class to update an Image field. For example, to update the Image field named ImageField in the `/Sitecore/Content/Home item` in the Master database to the `/Sitecore/Media Library/Images/Sample image`:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sampleItem =

master.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/images/sample");

Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem sampleMedia =

new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(sampleItem);

Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = home.Fields["imagefield"];

if (imageField.MediaID != sampleMedia.ID) {

    home.Editing.BeginEdit();
    imageField.Clear();
    imageField.MediaID = sampleMedia.ID;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleMedia.Alt))
    {
        imageField.Alt = sampleMedia.Alt;
    }
    else
    {
        imageField.Alt = sampleMedia.DisplayName;
    }

    home.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

For more reference go to - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/access-image-fields.html

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, But i want to replace or add new image from outside of sitecore by using Memory stream or URLs

Comment: Then check these - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-to-upload-an-image-programmatically-from-url 
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/adding-a-file-to-the-sitecore-media-library-programatically/

Comment: If i'm adding any image into same path getting error as "Sitecore.Exceptions.DuplicateItemNameException:". I have set existing sitecore path but not working even image name is different. Getting error for PATH only

Comment: The setting name “AllowDuplicateItemNamesOnSameLevel” is in Sitecore.config file under App_Config folder. Set it to false to restrict the duplication then try.

Comment: I'm using sitecore 10 headless with Docker. So not able to find above path in my project

Comment: try to create patch file and override this setting.

Comment: Could you please share some example to create patch file for the same.